# How do i prevent duplicate entries to a table in mysql and python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm making a script which inserts data into a MySQL Database and I need to only insert Data once a day from multiple sensors each but I can't find a way to prevent multiple entries. Is there a way to check if the entry exists and if it doesn't only then insert the data?
Here is the part of my code which contains a syntax error.
Sorry if the mistake is obvious, I'm new to SQL.

```
 mycursor.execute('''
        SELECT * FROM MotorControlDB.FSYesterdayVolume
        IF Date = %s AND DeviceID = %s THEN
          INSERT INTO MotorControlDB.FSYesterdayVolume(DeviceID, VolumeYesterday, Date)
          VALUES (%s, '%s', '%s')
        END IF
        ''', (YesterdayDate, '2-ES-WC-FS', '2-ES-WC-FS', EastVolumeYesterday, YesterdayDate))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your query I see that you're checking `Date+DeviceID` combination. So, I assume these two forms a unique ID. With this, you can create a unique index on your table to prevent duplication. Example:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniq_idx
ON MotorControlDB.FSYesterdayVolume(Date,DeviceID);
```

Then you can simply use `INSERT IGNORE` like below:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO MotorControlDB.FSYesterdayVolume(DeviceID, VolumeYesterday, Date)
VALUES (%s, '%s', '%s')
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you would normally do this is create a 'unique index' in the created table definition. Then there's no way any code could insert duplicates. In our case the unique constraint columns would be (DeviceID, Date).

Having that safety in place, the program can do one of a few things: (1) try the insert and if it fails with a duplicate error, update if so desired; (2) first try select, if it succeeds update else insert; (3) many databases have a mechanism of doing what's known as an 'UPSERT' which is a combination of INSERT-and-UPDATE-if-exists.

Comment: I can't use a unique index because I have multiple Devices which insert their data in a single table I have about 9 devices and they all need to insert once a day.

Comment: By creating a single UNIQUE index on two columns together in means that you can have many DeviceID rows and many Day rows but only one row with a specific (DeviceID, Day) combination.